# Updating installed plugins when upgrading Cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I've upgraded my Cordova project (to 3.4.0).

There's simple instructions on [upgrading the Cordova framework](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/02/20/cordova-340.html), but I cannot find documentation on bringing plugins to their latest versions (especially the cordova-* set of plugins).

Do each of them need to be individually rm'ed and add'ed again, or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this recent post](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/09/22/plugins-release.html) on the Apache Cordova website the way to update a plugin is by removing and then re-adding it, e.g.:

> cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file
>
> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file

No mention of a way 'update' all installed plugins at once though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can re-run 'cordova plugin add **_**' and it will overwrite any existing plugins with the latest one it finds in the registry.

There is not 'cordova plugin update' command.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to be easiest way to update, though it returns a message 'Package ... already installed', as if no action had been taken. Just to clarify, of course, that '_' in the command given above should be replaced with the package name, and that the command needs to be run individually for each package to be updated.

Comment: Added new answer based on post on Cordova's website about doing an 'rm' then 'add' to update a plugin (one at a time).

Answer (score 0):

Some plugin will don't have id same as in the old Cordova version.
So, you should get all the current plugin, remove and add it again for each plugin.

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.device
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```